# Is create a HTTP GET Request to domain for detect disposable mail is a bad concept?

Tags: email, security

Disposable Mail in this term is a temporary mail server, that mostly work for 15 minutes to 1 hour for doing send and receive mail service. The problem is when we create a free service for new registered user in a website or apps, people keep creating email using disposable mail. This is really bad.

So, I create a simple request to the domain with only HTTP GET Request. When it breaks or return as not reached the server, this domain will detected as temp mail.

As long as I am trying to block disposable mail using this scenario,, this still looks good. I have blocked many disposable email without creating a list of it. And every domain that passed the GET Request test is truly a real mail.

Is this a good concept? is there domain from real email provider that fail on a GET Request?

Comment: *"And every domain that passed the GET Request test is truly a real mail."* - You might have been lucky up till now, but don't count on it. There are disposable mail domains that will pass through this test.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not use this signal to outright block emails. There are cases where domains host email for honest individuals, but have no website. An apparent example at the time of writing is `@campbell.id`. Let's look at this in some more technical detail:

1. To receive mail, a domain must have an `MX` DNS record and an SMTP server behind it.
2. To handle an HTTP GET request, a domain must have an `A` DNS record (or a `CNAME` leading to an `A`, or a `AAAA` for ipv6, you get the idea), and an HTTP server behind it.

You've found correlations in which short lived, disposable email domains often do #1 but not #2, while "legitimate" email domains often do both #1 and #2. However this is not required nor guaranteed, and "legitimate" domains which do only #1 and not #2 exist. *Vanity domains* like `@campbell.id` above offer some good examples, where people may want a nice looking, personal email address (so do #1) but not care to host a personal website (so don't do #2). There are likely many others, and not only limited to vanity domains.

While you should not use this signal to outright block emails, it could still be used as one in a set of signals where others exist that can offset it. Tuning and maintaining such a system to get good results easily becomes a job in its own though, so consider using an existing service rather than building your own. (Upollo is one I happen to be involved with).

Another approach for using a signal that is often but not always correct can be to trigger some additional verification or followup instead of outright blocking users. However you want to be quite confident, which I don't think you can be with this one signal, or else it becomes unfairly onerous for a specific subset of legitimate users.